# Добавление исключения адресов в свойства обозревателя с помощью С++

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10

Перейду сразу к сути дела, есть программа, которая подключается к локальный сети и оттуда запускает уже другую программу. Так вот, на компьютерах локальная сеть помечена как "недоверенная" Впоследствии чего, запустить программу, которая лежит по пути в локальной файловой сети выдаёт окно с подтверждением, что это недоверенный источник(не я занимался их настройками, увы) и программа не может быть запущена без подтверждения. Это можно сделать вручную, но для каждый учётки и компа делать естественно муторно. И как можно программно добавлять в местную интрасеть узлы(напр. 192.168.10.1) как исключения, дабы не было окна подтверждения? Желательно поподробнее, я недавно в программировании
(Система - Win10, 64x)

[image: Свойства обозревателя]

Данный скриншот привёл для примера.

Answer (score 1):

Используя [Security Zones API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms537181(v%3dvs.85)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Urlmon.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    IInternetSecurityManager *pSecurityManager = NULL;
    HRESULT hResult = S_OK;

    CoInitialize(NULL);
    hResult=CoCreateInstance( CLSID_InternetSecurityManager,  NULL, 
                              CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IInternetSecurityManager,
                              (void **)&pSecurityManager );

    if (SUCCEEDED(hResult))
    {
        hResult=pSecurityManager->SetZoneMapping(
          URLZONE_INTRANET, L"https://example.com", SZM_CREATE 
          );

        if(SUCCEEDED(hResult)) wprintf(L"Done!\n",(UINT)hResult);
        else wprintf(L"SetZoneMapping failed: 0x%x\n",(UINT)hResult);

        pSecurityManager->Release();
    }
    else{
        wprintf(L"CoCreateInstance failed: 0x%x\n",(UINT)hResult);
    }


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```